# Как реализовать поиск по сайту?

Tags: поиск, парсер, java, html

Мне нужно реализовать поиск по сайту требуемой информации. Посоветуйте, на что глянуть ?

PS: язык - java.

Comment: Поиск по сайту изнутри (реализация функционала самого сайта) или снаружи (стучишься из сети на сайт, скачиваешь страницы и ищешь в них что-то)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если хочешь ОЧЕНЬ крутой поиск - то это sphinx (Бог поиска) . Это программа (демон). java поддерживается официально для sphinx.