# Принцип работы поиска по сайту

Tags: база-данных, алгоритм, поиск, структуры-данных, поисковые-системы

Как можно концептуально организовать поиск по сайту (сайт на системе управления)?

Посмотрел заданные вопросы:

- [Быстрый поиск по сайту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998384/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83)
- [Как реализовать поиск по сайту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/142302/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83)
- [Реализовать поиск по сайту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1305024/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%83)

Погуглил, но особо не нашел откуда можно изучить вопрос. Интересует по каким принципам это может работать.

Из пришедших в голову вариантов:

- Поиск по полям таблиц.
- Создать отдельную таблицу допустим `search` пробежаться по всем страницам сайта и записывать их содержимое в эту таблицу, поиск делать уже по этой таблице, а при обновлении контента заново индексировать страницу где, что то обновилось (но что делать если на странице динамический контент не знаю).

И как работают поисковые системы ([например гугл](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/basics/how-search-works?hl=ru))

Comment: [Пишем движок полнотекстового поиска на Go](https://habr.com/ru/post/519024/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для страниц с динамическим контентом нужен алгоритм извлечения полезной информации из контента. Для HTML-текста один из лучших алгоритмов - [readability](https://github.com/mozilla/readability). Он проставляет каждому тегу так называемый `readability score`, а также уделяется огромное внимание `meta`-данным страницы.

Для поиска неточных форм слов можно использовать [Стеммер Портера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0). Это самый простой способ, но можно погуглить и другие способы лексического морфологического синтаксического анализа выражений.

Для поиска по всем форматам контента (html, txt, doc, xls, pdf) есть софт [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).